# Trying to add a class atribute to css

Tags: css, image, class

I've gotten this code to work propely,

`<img src="forest.gif" class="magnify" border="0" />`

but I do not want to add class="magnify" to each img. I want to make it part of my style sheet, and have it effect all images. Is that possible?

Comment: Surely, what you need to do then is to change whatever is currently looking for the class `magnify` to instead look for `img` elements. But since you haven't shown us whatever this thing is that's performing this search, we can't tell you how to update it.

Comment: if you really want ALL the images, why don't you put your css on your img tag and not on class magnify

Comment: @user2642149: if you need to override the css settings for particular images, you can still do so by adding another css rule with a more specific selector _after_ your general one.

Comment: This is what I'm doing. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use JavaScript if you want to add it at a time after the page is loaded.

In JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
         $(this).addClass('magnify');
    });
});
```

Comment: It couldn't be loaded with the page?

Comment: Either edit the jquery magnify source to magnify all `img` tags instead of `magnify` class, or manually apply the `magnify` class to all images as you're doing already. There is no way that I know of to apply a class to all `img` elements on a page without putting the class attributes in the html or using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.magnify {
    color: red
    blabla...
}
```

to

```
img {
    color: red
    blabla...
}
```

that gives style to all images.

Comment: The the class=magnify is needed for the enable the magnify effect on an image

Comment: I need to be able to add that to img, if that makes sense

Comment: @user2642149 - what is *providing* the "magnify effect"? It's that that will need changing (if possible), and you haven't shown it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `TAG` specific style sheet definition. Define your own CSS class to override it on specific image tag when needed, you can even combine more than one CSS class.

```
img {
  border: 0;
  attribute1: 1abc;
  .
  .
  .
  attributeN: nABC;
  }
```

Including example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {
      margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      border: 2px 2px 2px 2px
    }

    h1, h2, h3 {
      font-size: 12pt;
    }
</style>
```

Including additional example:

```
<style type="text/css">
 img.magnify.magnifyEx {
   border: 2px;
 }
 </style
```

Comment: It's plain Cascading Style Definition only.

Comment: I figured since it was using a class to trigger the effect, that it could be incorporated into my style sheet, but no?

Comment: Use like ´img.magnify { }´ will do the work, you could leave empty or provide addition attributes.